# How should I sample the signal $f(t) = \sin(24t)^3\chi_{[0,0.52]}$ on the interval $[0,1.25]$?

Tags: matlab, sampling, continuous-signals

I am from an applied math/PDE background and I don't usually deal with proper sampling and signal processing. I just take roughly what seems to be a good number of samples. But I would like to be precise with a signal I'm currently dealing with:
$$
f(t) = sin(24t)^3\chi_{[0,0.52]},
$$
which is shown in the image below on the interval $[0,1.25]$. My matlab code is:

```
sig_fn = @(t) \sin(24*t).^3.*(0<=t).*(t<=0.52);

time_N = 1500;
T = 1.25;
dt = T/time_N;

t = linspace(0,T,time_N+1);

figure
hold on, grid on
plot(t,sig_fn(t))
```

How should I sample this signal in Matlab so that it is accurately resolved, that is, what time-step size (or how many time-steps) should I choose? Clearly it is accurately resolved in the image but I have used 1500 time-step for this image which seems to be much more than necessary. By accurate, I mean the relative error between the true signal and the sampled signal is less than, say, $10^{-2}$ in the $l^2$ or $l^\infty$ norms.

I want to use the minimum number of time-steps that still gives an accurate resolution of the signal. So how do I determine how many time steps to use? What changes would a signal processing expert make to the above code so that the correct number of time-steps are chosen to achieve a specific relative error?

On a related note, is there any pre-processing/filtering I could do with the signal that would allow me to use less samples and still get an accurate resolution?
[image]

Comment: When sampling a continuous-time signal, we don't typically think about "relative error between the true signal and the sampled signal." After all, assuming ideal sampling, the samples that you take are *exactly* equal to the true signal values at the sampling instants. Instead, choosing a sample rate is typically taken with the [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) in mind to ensure that you can unambiguously reconstruct the original continuous time signal from the sample values.

Comment: How do you define the relative error between a continuous and a sampled signal? How do you define "accurate resolution"? I don't think that the question can be answered in its current state.

Comment: @JasonR What changes need to be made to the Matlab code so that the number of time-steps/sample rate is set in accordance with the sampling theorem?